# Updating glib 2.22 or later on ubuntu 14.04 facing issues.

Tags: glibc

I'm installing 'libsnarf" which requires glib_ version 2.22 or later

Im on ubuntu 14.04 with

> ldd --version Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) 2.19

when I

> sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-d

it says i already have the latest package ? What should i do? thanks.

Comment: Give me the download link of `libsnarf`

Comment: http://tools.netsa.cert.org/snarf/download.html

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0`

Comment: And the output of `find /usr/lib -type f -name 'glib-2.0.pc'`

Comment: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc

Comment: 2.40.2 pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0